# AWS IAM Access for Developers (Sandbox)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, sandbox, provisioning

I have found a few articles/post that discuss this issue, but no definitive solution that will meet my needs.

My company uses an AWS Landing Zone with SSO. To date, the cloud team has been creating IAM roles/policies that are required by developers to experiment with services and create proofs-of-concept, however, developers have raise that this is too slow/restrictive and requested the ability to create the IAM policies/roles they need in their development account. I am in the tricky situation of preserving the integrity of our AWS environment while not inhibiting developer experimentation and innovation.

Is there a recommended approach to managing this? I had thought of only allowing passing of roles prefixed with a path of "dev/" for example, but this doesn't address creating new roles or policies where developers could allow iam:*/resource:*. I would also like to provision a new sandbox account that is disconnected from the rest of the environment (network, local IAM users rather than SSO) to reduce the blast radius of any developer misconfiguration. The only tie back to the company would be that billing is consolidated under the company AWS organization.

Currently, developers have been assigned PowerUser access plus some key IAM actions such as PassRole in their development account. Most of our developers are new to AWS so managing this via the console is preferable for this sandbox account (rather than via a CI/CD pipeline).

Any suggestions appreciated!

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips regarding how my company is addressing part of your concerns (The company is an enterprise with dedicated architectural support from Amazon. I have no idea if they are strictly following what Amazon suggests though, so keep that in mind)

- All users are created managed in the central company account **with no right**, all billing delegates to specific billing account.
- All users must then assume the role in their respective working accounts ( Developer@SalesAccount or Manager@MarketingAccount )
- [Permission boundaries](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/delegate-permission-management-to-developers-using-iam-permissions-boundaries/) are set to prevent the IAM user from giving permission surpass their own permission level
- [SCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) are applied where appropriate

Comment: Thanks for the information qkhanhpro. We already have centralised user management with users assuming the appropriate roles assigned to them in target accounts, so I think that cover point 1 & 2. I implemented permission boundaries which seems to meet our needs quite well. The only issue I've found is when the AWS management console sometime automatically creates roles (dms to cloudwatch logs in this case), it doesn't know to set the IAM permission boundary and falls over. Prob a subject for another post though :)

Comment: Hmm. If you are talking about service linked role and IAM user could abuse it to escalate previllege, I don't think It will work 

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/acnif6/what_is_the_best_practice_for_restricting_the/